# WebSocket Client in Lua

Tags: network-programming, lua, client, websocket

Is there a WebSocket client (not a server) written for Lua.

It can either be a C module or in pure Lua.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up and switched to regular sockets on the server side. It was much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,there is https://github.com/lipp/lua-websockets. It does not add any C bindings, but relies on luasocket, lpack and depending on your usage scenario (lua-ev).

Comment: Also it has 3 versions of clients:
synchronous,
coroutine based (copas),
asynchronous (lua-ev)

Answer (score 0):

Yep.  http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/

Comment: Ok. That does raw sockets. I was hoping to avoid that. Is there no prebuilt api for WebSockets?

Comment: None that I have found, but I did find this: http://www.wellho.net/resources/ex.php4?item=u116/webclient

Answer (score 0):

I could only find this pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/f50d79dcd

Comment: that doesn't seem to be a client, it seems to be a server.